# This resource not found in jDeveloper OSB Application

Tags: jdeveloper, servicebus, osb, oracle-service-bus

Can someone help me? I've installed the jdeveloper version 12.2.1.2.0 with SOA QUICK START installer, and when I open my osb project I have too many exceptions and proxy service pipeline has the errors. It doesn't see another resources in osb project for example transformations and the wsdl files, but really they are in the project. If I remove code from xquery file, add it again and save, pipeline begins to see the resource. 
Did someone resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You must clean and refresh the project. 
From JDeveloper menu go to Build-> Clean All and Refresh Application.

Comment: Hi,  thank you for answer,  but this didn't help me.